# Images are adding multiple on update + rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After editing designers page, i.e to add the image , after clicking save images are sshowing multilple, i'll explain breifly about the issue
   Consider admin added designer image & then later admin wants to change new image then previous image filed is showing & after updating 2 images are showing

```
class Admin::DesignersController < Admin::AdminController
  before_filter :find_designer, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :download]

 before_filter :verify_user_logged_in
  def index
   @designers = Designer.unscoped.search do |query|
   query.search_columns :name, :company, :description, :email_ids
   query.scope :sort_by, "name"
   query.paginate page_number
   query.filter params[:q]
  end
end

def new
 @designer = Designer.new
end

def create
 @designer = Designer.new(designer_params)
 if @designer.save
   redirect_to admin_designers_path
 else
  render :new
 end
end

def edit
end

def update
 if @designer.update_attributes(designer_params)
  redirect_to admin_designers_path
 else
   render :edit
 end
end

def destroy
 @designer.mark_deleted
  head :ok
end
def download
 respond_to do |format|
   format.xls {
     @products = @designer.products
     render :xls => "#{@designer.permalink}-products"
    }
 end
end

private
def find_designer
@designer = Designer.find_by_id(params[:id])
redirect_to admin_designers_path if @designer.nil?
end

private
def verify_user_logged_in
  redirect_to root_path and return if current_user.nil?
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user.internal?
end

private
 def designer_params
  params.require(:designer).permit(:name, :company, :email_ids, :phone,   :website, :designer_type, :description, :warehouse_address,  :corporate_address, :landmark, :city, :state, :pincode, :handling_shipping,  :info, :keywords, :status, designer_images_attributes: [:image])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `:id`  to `designer_images_attributes` in `designer_params` will work. As the id for the desiner_images are not provided it will create a new record everytime without updating the designer_image_attributes.